# Why using "if __name__=='__main__': main()" and not simply "main()" in Python?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Also, why do we use the underscores? After all, I define the main method as `main()`, not as `__main__()`.

Comment: Someone will give you a detailed answer, but my take on this is "Because it's Python, not C"

Comment: `__main__` has nothing whatever to do with whether or not you define a function called `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

> When the Python interpreter reads a source file, it executes all of
>   the code found in it. Before executing the code, it will define a few
>   special variables. For example, if the python interpreter is running
>   that module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special
>   `__name__` variable to have a value `"__main__"`. If this file is being imported from another module, `__name__` will be set to the module's
>   name.
>
> In the case of your script, let's assume that it's executing as the
>   main function, e.g. you said something like
>
> `python threading_example.py`
>
> on the command line. After setting up the special variables, it will
>   execute the import statement and load those modules. It will then
>   evaluate the def block, creating a function object and creating a
>   variable called myfunction that points to the function object. It will
>   then read the if statement and see that `__name__` does equal
>   `"__main__"`, so it will execute the block shown there.
>
> One of the reasons for doing this is that sometimes you write a module
>   (a .py file) where it can be executed directly. Alternatively, it can
>   also be imported and used in another module. By doing the main check,
>   you can have that code only execute when you want to run the module as
>   a program and not have it execute when someone just wants to import
>   your module and call your functions themselves.

taken from here: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know "main" function like C or Java.
You have more explication here : [what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

When the python interpreter is running a module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special __name__ variable to have a value "__main__", not as main().